# When does scheme evaluate quote?

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp

`(car ''abracadabra)` is equivalent to `(car (quote (quote abracadabra))`, and it evaluates to `(car (quote abracadabra))` --> `quote`

On the othe hand `(car (quote (a b)))` evaluates to `a`, which to me makes sense intuitively.

So my question is, why does Scheme not evaluate the second quote in `(car (quote (quote abracadabra))` (i.e. evaluate `(car (quote abracadabra))` to `(car abracadabra)`), but does evaluade the quote in `(car (quote (a b)))` (i.e. why isn't the answer `quote`)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this expression:

```
(car (quote (quote abracadabra)))
=> 'quote
```

The inner `quote` doesn't get evaluated, it's just a *symbol*, with no particular meaning. You might as well change it for anything else, with the same results:

```
(car (quote (foobar abracadabra)))
=> 'foobar
```

Inside a quoted expression, other expressions won't get evaluated. We could use [quasiquoting](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/quasiquote.html) to force evaluation, now this will attempt to evaluate the inner quote, resulting in a different error for each case:

```
(car (quasiquote (unquote (quote abracadabra))))  ; (car `,(quote abracadabra))
=> car: contract violation expected: pair? given: 'abracadabra

(car (quasiquote (unquote (foobar abracadabra)))) ; (car `,(foobar abracadabra))
=> foobar: unbound identifier in module in: foobar
```

Answer (score 2):

Scheme doesn't evaluate the inner quote because the inner quote is inside the outer quote and expressions inside a quote aren't evaluated. That is if you write `(quote foo)`, then `foo` will never be evaluated - even if `foo` is another call to `quote`.

Answer (score 1):

When scheme evaluates a combination it evaluates the operator. Then it will apply if it's a special form or macro. If not, it will evaluate each operands before applying.

```
(car (quote (quote abracadabra)))
```

Can be evaluated like this*

- car evaluates to #<proc car>. since it's a procedure evaluate all operands in any order
- (quote (quote abracadabra)) is a combination, thus

  - quote is evaluated => #<macro quote> and since its a macro/special form do macro-apply
  - apply-macro (#<macro quote> (quote abracadabra))) => (quote abracadabra)
- apply-proc (#<proc car> (quote abracadabra)) => quote

*Actually Scheme can shadow any keyword so the context is very important. E.g.:

```
(let ((quote list) (abracadabra 'simsalabim))
  (car (quote (quote abracadabra)))) 
==> (simsalabim)
```